# Apply MSI with Entity Framework Core Code first approach?

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework-core, ef-code-first, visual-studio-2022, azure-managed-identity

I am trying to use code first approach with MSI on my local machine to connect to SQL server. I am using DBInterceptor to generate the token using `Azure.Identity` package. When I run the migrations, it gives me below error:

> Login failed for user ''. The server is not currently configured to accept the token.

I have database owner permissions to access the database. But, I am not sure how to fix this error? did anyone try to work with code first + MSI approach?

Comment: Are you using Azure SQL Database?

Comment: You do not need an interceptor: https://erikej.github.io/efcore/azure/2021/04/20/efcore-managed-identity.html

Comment: @David Browne - Microsoft   yes, I am using Azure SQL Database.